# How (can?) I enable WebKit AudioContext on the Amazon Silk browser?

Tags: android, kindle-fire, webkitaudiocontext, amazon-silk

I'm working on a Web App and we're using the WebKit AudioContext.

I'm trying to find the easiest way to run it on a Kindle Fire HD table (Android 4.x).
(Chrome is not installed by default and it's not in the App Store for the Kindle)

The Silk browser doesn't seem to support the Webkit AudioContext, but I thought there might be a way to enable it. (It's an optional setting in Chrome)

Comment: Silk is probably running a little behind the core WebKit that Chrome is based on so if a feature is only beta/optional in Chrome I'd expect it to be a little while before it makes it into other browsers. I've not checked but is it supported in Safari on iOS yet?

Comment: This issue is that the preinstalled browser on the Kindle is the Silk browser, so that's what the user's stuck with unless they go through hoops to get chrome.

Comment: agreed, but does Chrome on Android (especially for those suck on 2.x or even 4.0) give you this ability either? Silk does pick new capabilities up all the time

Comment: I've not been able to find the latest Chrome browser .apk for Android so I'm not sure. But I'd think that Chrome on ANDROID would be the Class from which everything else instantiates <g>. I.e., the latest and greatest.  But I'm honestly not sure at this point.

Comment: Trying the samples from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/jamwithchrome-audio/ on Chrome29 on Android 4.3 ... no audio

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, Chrome on Kindle Fire  (and Chrome on Galaxy Tab/Android 4.2.2) tells me to "hop on over to your laptop or desktop computer to Jam" :-(

Comment: I guess that is the answer at the moment :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AudioContext() doesn't exist on some phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977033/audiocontext-doesnt-exist-on-some-phones)